# ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram'. Tryon to create a python telegram bot and getting this error

Tags: python, bots, telegram

ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram'

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes, MessageHandler, filters 
import json
import random
```

Tried reinstalling telegram

Comment: check whether the module is installed or not using `pip frreze` command

Comment: checked it , it is installed

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the terminal:

```
pip uninstall python-telegram-bot -y
pip install -U python-telegram-bot
```

It will install the latest verison of python-telegram-bot. And it'll fix the problem